# how to remove member in group without admin

Tags: deja-dup

Sir 
I need one help
we have our community small group
one of my friend created last month unfortunately he deactivated that account so there is no Admin here
how can i make admin there 
we wants to block one person
how to help me please 
akbarali

Comment: Could you open terminal and update your question with: `groups yourUser` output, content of `/etc/group` file, community small group name and user name you want to deactivate?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have read your question correctly, the following instructions should work.

---

### **How to add an existing user to the admin / sudo group using Recovery Mode**

First shutdown your computer.

Then restart whilst holding the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to load grub menu.

Select **recovery mode** from the grub menu.

Select **drop to root shell** from the recovery menu.

Then use the following command to remount the drive with write permissions.

`mount -o rw,remount /`

Next use the following command to add a user to the sudo / admin group.

`adduser username sudo`

You must replace `username` with your user name  ie.

```
adduser akbar sudo
```

You should now see a message saying 'adding user' followed by 'done'.

Finally use `shutdown -r now` to restart the computer.

---

You will now have a working admin account enabling you to make the required changes.